# Cauchy Sequence of Rational Numbers - Prove another sequence is Cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series, rational-numbers, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers. Prove that $\dfrac{4a_n^4}{2 + a_n^3}$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

I know that Cauchy sequences can be added, subtracted and multiplied but I'm not sure how to apply this to the proof.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of rational numbers converging to $-\sqrt[3]{2}$.  (The choice of rational $a_n$ is possible thanks to the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$.)  Since it's convergent, it's Cauchy, and thus bounded.

The fraction $\dfrac{4a_n^4}{2+a_n^3}$ has bounded nominator, but its denominator tends to zero as $n$ tends to infinity.  Therefore, this fraction is not bounded, thus it's not Cauchy.

Comment: So to prove that it's Cauchy I would need to prove that it's bounded? so for example if the problem was $\dfrac{4a_n^4}{2 + a_n^2}$ then both the nominator and denominator would be bounded?

Comment: @kat Boundedness is a *necessary* condition for a sequence to be Cauchy, but not a *sufficient* condition.  Take $(-1)^n$ as an example.  For your fraction in the comment, take $a_n \to \pm\sqrt2$ instead to see that the denominator tends to zero, so by the same reasoning, it's not Cauchy.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I don't think $a_n\to\pm\sqrt2$ causes any difficulty in the $4a_n^4/(2+a_n^2)$ example.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks for comment.  You're right.  I confused $a_n^2 + 2$ with $a_n^2 - 2$.

Comment: @kat Sorry for my confusion about the deominator.  For $\dfrac{4a_n^4}{2 + a_n^2}$, yes, both the numerator and denominator are bounded.